# Prove that if $X$ is a subset of $Y$ then $X$ intersect $Z$ is a subset of $Y$ intersect $Z$ for all sets $X$, $Y$, $Z$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How do you write this proof? Say $Y = \{a, b, c, d\}$ and $X = \{a, c\}$ and $Z = \{a, d, e\}$. Then $X$ is indeed a subset of $Y$, however, $Z$ intersect $Y$ is $\{a, d\}$, and $Z$ intersect $X$ is just $\{a\}$, which is of course a subset of $Z$ intersect $Y$... but I still don't know how to write that as a proof or how validating that is. Doesn't seem too concrete or all-encompassing to me. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $a \in X \cap Z$. Then $a \in X$ and $a \in Z$. Since $X \subseteq Y$, we see that $a \in Y$. Since $a \in Y$ and $a \in Z$, we have $a \in Y \cap Z$.
Since $a$ was an arbitrarily chosen element of $X \cap Z$ and $a \in Y \cap Z$, we have the desired result.